# navbar brand color on click different between safari and chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just got a new macbook so I am using safari again.  I just noticed that when I click on the navbar brand in Safari, the hover color stays only as long as I'm hovering over the navbar brand.  On the other hand in Chrome it stays the hover color after clicking until I click somewhere else.

Here's a example - try it in Safari and Chrome:  click on the navbar-brand and then move your mouse out of it.  In Safari, the hover color will go away.  In Chrome, the hover color will stay and it will go away only after you click somewhere else.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/simplex/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    Brand
  </a>
</nav>
```

Which is the correct behavior?  I like the way it works on Safari.  How can I make chrome do the same?  When I check the dev tools I see that the color only shows on hover..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `:focus` property added to your bootstrap css that is causing this. Try overriding it like:

```
a:focus {
  color: #d9230f;
}
```

You might need to add `!important` to the above style.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you!  So I guess that is normal?

Comment: You're welcome. It's totally fine to override the default bootstrap styles.